# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli' in codeigniter ubuntu

Tags: apache, codeigniter, ubuntu, php-7.2

I have installed php7.2, apache and mysql.
When I copied codeigniter folder in my `var/www/html` it runs but give one error as

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli'
>   (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/php_mysqli
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/php_mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/php_mysqli.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/php_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory))
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

I search for the same and tried with different solution as updating `php.ini` file but still getting the same error.

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` OS

Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a PHP issue and not CodeIgniter. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292104/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php-20151012)

Comment: Make sure that you installed lamp stack correctly and added all required dependencies.

Comment: have you installed php7.2-mysql? and restarted server after installation?

Answer (score 2):

Install php extension for mysql.

use this command

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

After installation restart apache with this command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**update**

If `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

not work for you then you should use

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Comment: php-mysql is installed and it is working fine with core php but not with codeigniter.

Comment: Tried both ways but anyone didn't help me.

Comment: @Kosmos First check the php version used by the web server it could be different than the version returned by `php --version` cmd. After knowing the php version try installing the php-mysql package for that php version using the cmd as `sudo apt-get install php<version>-mysql`. Don't forget to replace <version> with the one used by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You should open php.ini file and check if the line:

```
 extension=mysqli.so
```

presented and not commented  with # sign

Comment: php.ini lines are commented with ;