# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so'

Tags: php, typo3

I get the following Message during the INstalation of Typo3.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: ./mysqli.so (./mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./mysqli.so.so (./mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

For php -m everythings works fine, but my composer needs php8.1

Under php8.1 -m i get this error

I tried to reinstall the packages and php.

Comment: Can you provide more information? How do you use PHP, what webserver and how? PHP CLI is often NOT the same like PHP for your webserver. You need to make your webserver's PHP have the modules you need.

Comment: Remember, not all the PHP extensions come as part of a PHP install on linux, you may need to install this extension seperately

Comment: Change the pathname in `php.ini` to the absolute path of the library, not a `./` relative path.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292104/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php-20151012